# Print odd and even pages of pdf at different scale in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, printer

I would like to print odd pages at 50% scale and even pages at 90% scale. And it has to be 2-sided print. Any idea how can i do it?

System-

OS - Windows 10

Printer - HP LaserJet 1020

Answer (score 0):

Print the odd ones at the scale required,

Put the pages back in the paper drawer - making sure they are the correct way up,

Then print the even pages at the scale required.

Comment: Although this doesn't take into account "it has to be 2-sided print" probably is the best and only option.

Comment: You do finish with the doc printed on two sides....

Comment: Yes, you do :-)